# Need to Log App Start/Restart Reasons

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I am implementing an app in android which will be default launcher for an android device.

Since it is a default launcher, so every time it gets terminated because of some reason(may be system have terminated it or may be because of any ANR), it will automatically gets re-launched by android it self.
Now, we are interested in knowing why app was killed? or why it is starting?

Few Categories:

> FirstStart
>   Unknown
>   AutoRestart
>   AppCrashed
>   UserRestart

does android provide any kind of utility or way through which we can come to know why our app is starting?

Comment: there is no such library maybe you can use some analytics tools like webengage

Comment: Add Crashlytics to your app https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Answer (score 0):

[Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)

> When an app throws an exception, logcat shows a message followed by
>   the associated stack trace containing links to the line of code.
>
> You can detect what's going on in your application, what caused an
>   exception, where exactly it happened, you can write your own logs to debug application.

[image]

Comment: My app can crash because of many reasons. May be because of kernel panic, some other activity/process caused an ANR for my app. So suppose some exception happens in my app then my app will be re-started by android it self(as it is the default launcher). So when ever my app gets re-started, how will come to know why my app was stopped in the last iteration?

Comment: you can do it by Logcat, it will always show an exception if it crashes, in logcat if you tap on filter and select Show only selected Application, it will show all the previous logs even if the application crashes.

Comment: It looks like either you did not read the question posted or i could not make it clear enough.
Okay, I'll re-try.
We need to know why our app is starting/re-starting? we need to write the reasons based on what happened during last iteration of app life cycle.

Comment: so you don't want to know why the app crashed in the first place?

Comment: so you don't want to know why the app crashed in the first place, I thought your said "Now, we are interested in knowing why app was killed? or why it is starting?" Could you post some code? did you try to handle the exception?

Comment: I understand your answer which says that when your app got crashed at that time check logs why it is killed and fix it. But what we are trying to do is for analytics purpose. we will check in a week(for an example) how many times the app was started and for which reason. Based on this we will be checking the stability of the app during field trials. we are trying to achieve that.  
Yes, when we are developing we see the crash reasons from the logcat and we are fixing that but when it will be in field, we will not be able to provide exact number on how many times it got started by it self.